# File upload using Spring Boot fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to upload a file to a directory in the project, and it keeps giving me this error:

```
2021-06-17 21:56:28,660 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: MultipartFile resource [plan] cannot be resolved to absolute file path
```

My Controller's endpoint :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/projets", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<Projet> getProjet(@ModelAttribute Projet projet) throws IOException {
    log.info("Create a new project");
    Projet addedProjet = projetService.createProjet(projet);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(addedProjet, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

the code that throws the exception :

```
public Projet createProjet(Projet projet) throws IOException {
    saveFile(projet.getPlan());
    Etat etat = new Etat();
    etat.setEtat(Status.EN_COURS);
    ProjetEtat projetEtat = new ProjetEtat();
    projetEtat.setProjet(projet);
    projetEtat.setEtat(etat);
    projetEtat.setDate(LocalDate.now());
    projetEtatRepository.save(projetEtat);
    etatRepository.save(etat);
    projet.setIsCounted(true);
    return projetRepository.save(projet);
}

private void saveFile(MultipartFile uploadedFile) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(STORAGE_DIRECTORY + uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(uploadedFile.getBytes());
    fos.close();
}
```

I didn't find any similar issue in StackOverFlow, and when I used the debug mode, I found that the error starts in this line :

```
return projetRepository.save(projet);
```

even that I made the 'plan' attribute @Transient (which is of type MultiPartFile)

Thank you for your time

Comment: What is `MultipartFile`, and how did that map from JSON? It sounds like something related to a **form** POST, but the request content is not form data, so that likely can't work.